# Delete rows from csv/txt file by filtering on the basis of time

Tags: filter, rows

How to delete rows from csv/txt file by filtering on the basis of time. Delete all rows which lie outside time period 09:01 to 16:00 (Column 3)?

Column 3 contains only time in hh:mm format.

Whereas Column 2 contains only date (dtype int64).

There are no Headers.

Time dtype is object.

I am able to filter based on other columns but not able to deal with time.

My data looks like this:

```
RTY,20200401,07:10,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,20
RTY,20200401,08:15,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,250
RTY,20200401,09:00,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,155
RTY,20200401,09:01,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,10
RTY,20200401,09:05,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,63
RTY,20200401,09:16,964.80,964.80,951.25,956.20,4587,159
RTY,20200401,09:17,956.20,957.25,953.10,955.15,4555,578
RTY,20200401,10:18,954.95,959.00,954.95,958.55,5121,951
RTY,20200401,12:19,958.50,960.00,956.50,959.20,3944,753
RTY,20200401,15:20,959.30,962.55,958.25,959.35,7071,258
RTY,20200401,15:30,960.00,960.00,956.15,956.15,2991,89
RTY,20200401,15:40,955.25,955.90,953.90,954.65,3812,574
RTY,20200401,16:00,955.25,955.90,953.90,954.65,3812,46
RTY,20200401,17:00,954.65,956.00,954.00,955.05,2775,654
RTY,20200401,18:00,954.65,956.00,954.00,955.05,2775,259
RTY,20200402,07:15,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,71
RTY,20200402,08:15,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,359
RTY,20200402,09:01,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,452
RTY,20200402,09:05,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,256
RTY,20200402,09:15,964.80,964.80,964.80,964.80,456,96
RTY,20200402,09:18,964.80,964.80,951.25,956.20,4587,754
RTY,20200402,09:55,956.20,957.25,953.10,955.15,4555,145
RTY,20200402,10:28,954.95,959.00,954.95,958.55,5121,252
RTY,20200402,12:49,958.50,960.00,956.50,959.20,3944,59
RTY,20200402,15:25,959.30,962.55,958.25,959.35,7071,745
RTY,20200402,15:30,960.00,960.00,956.15,956.15,2991,352
RTY,20200402,15:45,955.25,955.90,953.90,954.65,3812,621
RTY,20200401,16:00,950.25,959.90,950.90,951.65,3812,25
RTY,20200402,17:55,954.65,956.00,954.00,955.05,2775,48
RTY,20200402,18:00,954.65,956.00,954.00,955.05,2775,100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that converts the strings to integers and then filters by value:

```
with open('example.txt','r') as file_handle:
    example_file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")

for line in example_file_content:
    line_as_list = line.split(",")
    # Delete all rows which lie outside time period 09:01 to 16:00
    if not (int(line_as_list[2].split(":")[0])<9 or
        int(line_as_list[2].split(":")[0])>16):
        print(line)
```

A better approach is to convert the column to datetime

```
import datetime

with open('example.txt','r') as file_handle:
    example_file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")

for line in example_file_content:
    line_as_list = line.split(",")
    # Delete all rows which lie outside time period 09:01 to 16:00
    if not ((datetime.datetime.strptime(line_as_list[2], '%H:%M')<
             datetime.datetime.strptime("09:01", '%H:%M')) or 
            (datetime.datetime.strptime(line_as_list[2], '%H:%M')>
             datetime.datetime.strptime("16:00", '%H:%M'))):
        print(line)
```